# Windows 10 screen automatically darkens when screen has darker content

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display

I have an Asus F510UA laptop running Windows 10 that I use on a daily basis. One of my major gripes with it is that whenever I go on battery power and view content that has a dark background, like VS Code, Intellij Idea, YouTube in dark mode, etc. it looks like the screen gets darker, even if my brightness is set at 100%.

I believe this is the case because whenever I then switch back to a bright website, (or in general away from the dark content) the screen brightens again after ~10 seconds. I don't think this is an optical illusion, however, I could be wrong.

My immediate thought is that when on battery power, Windows is doing some funky magic with the power plan that allows it to turn the screen brightness down, but I can't seem to find any setting to let me turn it off. Does anyone know what is happening here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turn off the adaptive brightness adjustment in the advanced power settings in Power Management, then turn off the Intel DPST option in the Advanced Power Settings.

The full name of INTEL DPST is Intel Display Power Saving Technology. This is a power saving technique for the display of the screen interface. For more information, you can browse this link: [Intel Display Power Saving Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Display_Power_Saving_Technology)

Comment: Ah, I already had adaptive brightness off, but I just turned Intel DPST off from the Intel Graphics Control Panel. We'll see how this works out.

Answer (score 0):

It really gave me a headache too. Just go to your external monitor settings in the On Screen Display (FYI click on external monitor buttons). Go to the Manual Image Adjust setting and "turn off" dynamic contrast. and Bob's your uncle.